# Pass parameters to javascript functions which is bind to events

Tags: javascript, jquery, cubism.js

I have a function like this :

```
 var that = this;
 this.context.on('focus', function(i) {
     var htmlElement = ele;
     var style = {left: 'auto', color: '#000000'};

     if(i !== null) {
         i = that.context.size()/2;
         style.left = i + 'px';
         //find htmlElement in DOM and apply style to it
     }
});
```

The htmlElement and style will var for me in different calls. I need to pass an option such as

`var options = {style: someVaue, htmlELement: somelement}`

to the function so that it could be called multiple times with different options. If I pass the `options` like this :

```
var that = this;
this.context.on('focus', function(i, options) {
    //use options.style and options.htmlElement 
});
```

It doesn't work that way. Clearly I am doing something wrong since the `function` bind to `focus` event of `this.context` has `i` as an param but can't accept any other param. Any kind of help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In this situation I normally add `data-*` attributes to the element and then retrieve them under the needed event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is good solution only for HTML5 code cuz the W3C validation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Retrieving element is not my problem. Passing the same to a function which could accept arguments is the one.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos that's correct, although HTML5 is widely supported now.

Comment: @Yogita088 that's what I'm saying - you can't pass extra parameters to the event handler. You would need to read the properties from the element which raised the event.

Comment: 1. As soon as you use a `var that = this` construct in JavaScript to force-feed a closure with some reference, you should really rethink the way you handle object references. Please use `.bind()` instead.

2. Also, are you sure about the comparison expression `i !== null` and then completely discarding the value of `i`?

Comment: Is it what you are looking for: `this.context.on('focus', function(options, e) {
    //use options.style and options.htmlElement 
}.bind(this, options));`  ?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry if I was unclear. I am talking about JavaScript `bind`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind Look at @A.Wolff 's comment

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Comment: @A.Wolff - write an answer building on that. :)

Comment: @atornblad But i'm really not sure this answers question because i'm not sure to understand OP's expected behaviour. The Rory way using data seems more relevant as how i understand it imho. And why not setting `this.options = {...};` then use it in handler

Comment: @atornblad: point 1 is taken care of. I am quite comfortable with closures. Point 2: yes, if i is null nothing has to be done.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes, I am looking for something like  `this.context.on('focus', function(options, e) { //use options.style and options.htmlElement }.bind(this, options))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have worked out a solution. Thanks everyone for their help. Here is how the options could be passed:

```
var that = this;
this.context.on('focus', function(i) {
    var options = {i: i, style: someValue, htmlElement: someElement};
    that.setStyle(options);
});

setStyle: function(options) {
    var htmlElement = options.htmlElement;
    var style = options.style;

    if(options.i !== null) {
        options.i = that.context.size()/2;
        style.left = i + 'px';
        //find htmlElement in DOM and apply style to it
    }
}
```

Please feel free to comment!!!